# ¿Cómo redirigir a otra página web?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

¿Como puedo redirigir a un usuario a otra página usando JavaScript o jQuery? y como puedo abrir una pestaña nueva?

Comment: Hola, depende del caso, agrega mas información (y el código que has intentado si existe) para entenderte mejor.

Comment: quiero desde el JavaScript cambiar la página en la que está el usuario, pero no quiero hacerlo desde un botón sino desde el JS directamente

Comment: puedes hacerlo con `window.location=url`, la pregunta es muy trivial seguro que te contestan, pero agrega mas información para mejorar la calidad de la pregunta, antes de que te voten negativo.

Answer (score 8):

Redirección basica

```
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
```

Nueva Pestaña

```
window.open("http://www.google.com");
```

Abrir en nueva ventana

```
window.open("http://www.google.com", "Tu Titulo", "width=500, height=500")
```

Y finalmente lo pones dentro del evento o función que quieras ej click:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
//Simple
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
//Pestaña
//  window.open("http://www.google.com");
//Ventana
//window.open("http://www.google.com", "Tu Titulo", "width=500, height=500")
});
```

Comment: gracias por compartir!

Answer (score 4):

Encontré algo muy interesante, cuando se usa `window.location.href` se agrega una página al historial de navegación, lo que hace que al dar click hacia atras toque recorrer todas las páginas por las que pasó el usuario. 
Mientras que si se usa `window.location.replace` al dar click para atrás se salta todas de una ves. Para ciertos casos de uso me parece una muy buena practica, por ejemplo estoy haciendo un formulario de varias páginas. No quiero que al dar hacia atrás el usuario se pueda devolver a ver los pasos del formulario. con replace el usuario se saltaría al comienzo del formulario o antes, según el punto desde el que empecé a usar `replace` en ves de `href`

```
// redirijo sin poderse devolver
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");

// redirección normal
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```